# What to return from fromSnapshot method if data is null

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm fetching data from Firestore using a `fromSnapshot` method like this :

```
 factory EventTypeModel.fromSnapshot(QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.data() != null) {
      final data = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final String name = data['name'] as String;

      return EventTypeModel(name: name);
    } else {}
  }
```

And I'm wondering what to put on the else in case the `data` is `null`

Answer (score 1):

If you have nothing to return then is good to simply return `null` because it is what null is designed for.

```
factory EventTypeModel.fromSnapshot(QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.data() != null) {
      final data = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final String name = data['name'] as String;

      return EventTypeModel(name: name);
    } else {
        return null; }
         }
```

but as it is not the complete functional code and if somehow it is required to return `EventTypeModel` you can modify your method as

```
factory EventTypeModel.fromSnapshot(QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.data() != null) {
      final data = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final String name = data['name'] as String;

      return EventTypeModel(name: name);
    } else {
       return EventTypeModel(name: "");
            }}
```